# ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognize internal webcam in alienware m14x r2

Tags: video, 16.04, webcam, alienware

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Alienware M14x R2 and ran Cheese or Skype to test the internal webcam but it doesn't show anything. On cheese it displays "There was an error playing video in the Webcam" or "No device found". On Skype it does not recognize the webcam either. I didn't try with other webcam software but i'm guessing the results will be the same. The internal webcam worked flawlessly in Ubuntu 14.04. Any tips or advice on how to solve the problem?

lsusb output:

```
luis@Luis-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 187c:0521 Alienware Corporation 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 064e:8128 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Did lsusb in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 and they both print the same output, however the integrated webcam works just fine only in 14.04.

lsmod output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
ctr                    16384  1
ccm                    20480  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  2
arc4                   16384  2
iwldvm                233472  0
snd_hda_codec_ca0132    57344  1
mac80211              737280  1 iwldvm
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  3   snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
snd_hda_core           73728  4  snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
coretemp               16384  0
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm_intel             172032  0
snd_pcm               106496  4    snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
uvcvideo               90112  0
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
videodev              176128  4  uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
dell_wmi               16384  0
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
cfg80211              565248  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
aesni_intel           167936  2
snd                    81920  20  snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_ca0132
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 20480  0
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei_me                 36864  0
serio_raw              16384  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
lpc_ich                24576  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
shpchp                 36864  0
mac_hid                16384  0
dell_smo8800           16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
squashfs               49152  1
overlay                49152  1
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
dm_mirror              24576  0
dm_region_hash         24576  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 20480  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
nouveau              1495040  1
i915                 1208320  5
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        139264  2 i915,nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  1
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
sdhci_pci              28672  0
drm                   360448  10 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
atl1c                  49152  0
wmi                    20480  3 dell_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  40960  3 i915,dell_wmi,nouveau
fjes                   28672  0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of 'lsusb' ?

Comment: `Bus 004 Device 003: ID 187c:0521 Alienware Corporation  
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 064e:8128 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
`

Comment: This webcam is hiding... Is there a function key combination that allows you to activate the webcam, fn+f1(I think)? If not, please post the output of "lsmod"

Comment: Looked for a function key but there isn't any. Tried fn+f1 and didn't work. I updated the original post with the lsmod output. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: The webcam is not hiding, we can see the `uvcvideo` kernel driver properly loaded.

Comment: That's odd. What is the output of "uname -r" on both 14.04 and 16.04? Also, was 14.04 installed on the machine before(not running via Live media)?

Comment: "uname -r" for Ubuntu 16.04: 4.4.0-21-generic / "uname -r" for Ubuntu 14.04:  4.2.0-36-generic
Tested both in live media and installed on the machine. Ubuntu 14.04 recognized the webcam both in live media and installed, but Ubuntu 16.04 did not in either way.  Thank you for your help!